# Openshift Django Pip permission denied

Tags: pip, openshift, openshift-cartridge

I have added a new package to the requirements.txt. When I push it with git to the openshift repository it fails to install it (after unpacking the requirements.txt and checking the pip dependencies). This is the error I am getting:

```
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/lib/openshift/{id}/.pip'
```

I am not sure why pip suddenly stopped to work, any ideas what it could be? I am using the Python 2.7 cartridge.

Comment: I'd try to make a clean build. Either with the `--force-clean-build` flag or by adding a force_clean_build marker file in the .openshift/markers/ directory.

Comment: Have you tried ssh to the gear and run the pip manually? I have experienced similar problems but this solved it for me.

Comment: Do you activate virtualenv? Can you use pip when you login through ssh?